# uniforms or vertex attributes when drawing lots of quads?

Tags: opengl-es, fragment-shader, vbo, vao

I'm working on a minimalist 2D user interface toolkit and need to draw lots of rectangles. I have a rendering class which draws all the rectangles, using a loop, each time setting uniforms for rectangle properties such as fill, color, border width, draw color inverted or not, etc. and then calling glDrawArrays with GL_TRIANGLES. My fragment shader uses these uniform values. For drawing a rectangle with inverted color I use glBlendFunc.

I have one VAO/VBO per rectangle. Obviously this is inefficient and I want to use one VAO across all my rectangles, and draw the rectangles with a single draw call instead of looping through them and setting uniform values and calling glDrawArrays each time.

I guess I could put each pair of triangles in a VBO, or perhaps use a single VBO for all rectangles, but what do I do with the uniforms, should I use vertex attributes instead, and try to pass these to the fragment shader, even if the properties per rectangle remain the same across vertices?

Answer (score 1):

Using a lot of draw calls is terrible for CPU load, so you are definitely going to want to batch as may rectangles as possible into a single draw.

If you batch into a single draw you can only use a single configuration of attribute streams, so all your rectangles in that batch need to be in the same set of VBOs and the same VAO layout.

It doesn't sound like you'll have a huge number of verts, so packing this into the attribute stream sounds as good as anything, but you could use a uniform array indexed by the instance ID (one instance per rectangle).